# XSLT delete zeros on the left side

Tags: xslt

i have this value:

```
<stredisko><xsl:value-of select="@STREDISKO" /></stredisko>
```

And @STREDISKO can have this values: 1000 or 0025  or 0002.
And i need to delete all zeros on the left side.
right results is:  1000 or 25 or 2.

have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(@STREDISKO)" />
```